# Two level menu, setting text-decoration property

Tags: html, css, text-decorations

Ok, this sounds kind of silly and I don't know if this is some kind of bug in css or what, but when I try to create two level menu where items on the first level have *text-decoration* property set to *underline*, I couldn't find a way to set *text-decoration* to *none* on the items on the second level.

```
<ul>
<li style="text-decoration:underline;">item1 
    <ul>
        <li style="text-decoration:none;">subitem1</li>
        <li>subitem2</li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Does anyone knows why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: using `float` in the second level also can fix your problem `<li style="text-decoration:none; float:left;">subitem1</li>`

Answer (score 1):

You could change your subitem to

```
<li style="text-decoration:none !important;">subitem1</li>
```

that should fix it for you.

However abuse of the !important rule is probably not the greatest way forward. A better strategy in the longer term would be to use a CSS file and add class attributes to your `li` elements.

Something like:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li class="main-item">item1 
    <ul>
        <li class="sub-item">subitem1</li>
        <li>subitem2</li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.main-item {
    text-decoration:underline;
}

.sub-item {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simple, first understand that if you are giving `text-decoration:underline;` to the first level list item then the same css property is gonna apply for for the child so what u can do is

.main-nav > li {text-decoration:underline;} -- with this the css is gonna apply for only the first level of list or the parent items. Note this will not apply for other child list.

With this u dont need to add css for child list

http://jsfiddle.net/qL3Bp/